# Python lendo banco postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, postgis

Em python utilizo callproc para executar uma função feita no banco de dados postgres. Funciona certo se acessa o banco pelo usuário com permissão total. Mas ocorre erro se acessa com usuário privado e indica erro de leitura do psycopg2, no trecho com instruções postgis st_transform(), st_distance(), st_setsrid(). Agradeço quem me dizer quais permissões são necessárias para usuário privado. pra rodar essas instruções.

Answer (score 0):

Quando da criação da função:

```
CREATE FUNCTION
```

o default é a opção `SECURITY INVOKER` que especifica que a função será executada com os privilégios do usuário que chamou a função. Se você deseja que a função seja executada com os privilégios do usuário que criou a função então utilize `SECURITY DEFINER`.